# Invisibility and GONE doesnt work after animation in android

Tags: java, android, android-animation

i use this code to when i click on a imagebox, run an animation on another object and dissaper itself via visibility.GONE. but it doesnt work!! here is my  code:

```
againbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //answer button on animation
            Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.askbtnonanim);
            anim2.setFillAfter(true);
            askbtn.startAnimation(anim2);

            //gone myselft (againbtn)
            againbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

if a delete 3 animation line from this code, everything is OK and works, but now it doesn't. but why? it's related to anim2.setFillAfter(true);  ???  i put this because  my animation run one time and dont reset!  please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement Animation Listener and in onAnimationEnd() you should perform your task... hope below code will help you...

```
anim2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    }           

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    }           

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        againbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);  //set your button visibility here
    }


});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this 
You have to clear the view animation then you can setVisibility

```js
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
view.clearAnimation();
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think put visibility button before animation coding the this might work

```
 againbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
//gone myselft (againbtn)
        againbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //answer button on animation
   Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,           R.anim.askbtnonanim);
         anim2.setFillAfter(true);
        askbtn.startAnimation(anim2);


    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling clearAnimation() on the view that is doing the animation before calling View.INVISIBLE, or GONE does the trick.

Answer (score -1):

use [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) for setting Button Visibility `GONE` when Animation end.

```
.....
anim2.setAnimationListener(animButnListener);
askbtn.startAnimation(anim2);
AnimationListener animButnListener = new AnimationListener(){
  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

   // make  Button Visibility GONE  here
    againbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
  //.......other AnimationListener methods
};
```