# disappear button itself

Tags: java, android, button

I do this code to disappear a button itself. but it doesn't work at all:

```
againbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        againbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

UPDATE:
my againbtn is invisible at activity load, and in my code, inside another buttun click, i make it visible with this code:

```
//answer button off animation
Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.askbtnoffanim);
anim2.setFillAfter(true);
askbtn.startAnimation(anim2);
```

as you can see im not using `againbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` or other things. animation itself appear the button. do you think my problem related to this? i try to do another animation to disappear the button itselft, it works but still `clicklistener` works for this button at his position area!!

why?

Comment: but in [Invisibility and GONE doesnt work after animation in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697880/invisibility-and-gone-doesnt-work-after-animation-in-android) you are saying working perfectly if you are if a delete 3 animation line from  button Onclick ?

Comment: yes, i was thinking it related to animation, but i remove it and still doesnt working!! why??

Comment: post full code depend on where u are setting `setOnClickListener` for button and make sure u are importing right package `import android.view.View;` for OnClickListener

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: this is my full code and i do it inside oncreate

Comment: use Log for check onClick event is firing or not on button click and show more code to get help because current code is fine  problem is in other part of code

Comment: is againbtn final/global?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: i update my question, please look at it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
againbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                againbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
}
```

});

Comment: r u getting any exception?

Comment: on click of button you want to just hide that button?

Answer (score 0):

check with the class which you imported, import the following class:

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

instead of:

import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;

I am giving the complete code here, you can use it:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And here is the activity_main.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```